# R formal argument "exact" matched by multiple actual arguments

Tags: r, radix

I'm getting this error every time I am returning an object.

```
sample_json

# Error in base::attr(..., exact = TRUE) : 
#  formal argument "exact" matched by multiple actual 
#  arguments
# Error in base::attr(..., exact = TRUE) : 
#  formal argument "exact" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

traceback() returns

```
5: gzfile(file, "wb")
4: save(x, options, file = output)
3: overridePrint(o$x, o$options, o$className, o$nRow, o$nCol)
2: print.data.frame(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

Comment: I would've provided one but I'm not sure how if it is occurring whenever I'm returning an object like above.

Comment: Can you use `traceback()`

Comment: Added to the question above.